# Программа для подсчёта елементов массива

Tags: c++

В программе для подсчёта ВСЁХ елементов массива выводяться не коректное значение, также имееться условие arr[i] >= 2 and arr[i] <= 10, при котором сумируються все значения массива соответствующие данному условию отдельно.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
// b переменная с улсловием 2<= n <= 10
// sum переменная в которой храниться количество елемента масива
    int n, b = 0, sum = 0;

    cout << "введите количество елементов масива n : ";
    cin >> n;

    int *arr = new int[n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 2 and arr[i] <= 10) {
            b = b + arr[i];
        }
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }

    cout << b << "\n";
    cout << sum << "\n";
    
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: А вводить значения элементов вы не планируете?... Суммируете просто мусор? И еще - `sum` не количество элементов (оно равно `n`, а сумма всех элементов...

Comment: У меня должно количество значений в массиве определяться через переменую `n` , а сами значения через `for`, тобиш если `n = 5`  то значения в массиве  должны быть `arr{1,2,3,4,5}`, однако что-то идеет и показуються неверные значения. По поводу `sum` и `n` спасибо что указали на ошибку.

Comment: Для начала заполните массив arr.

Comment: "*сами значения через for, тобиш если n = 5 то значения в массиве должны быть arr{1,2,3,4,5}*" - но для этого вы их должны в массив внести, правда? Цикла, вносящего значения в массив, у вас нет.